# Biblatex use of Volumes field with Techreport

Tags: biblatex

Anyone know if the `@techreport` type will pick up the `volumes` field in Biblatex so that one can indicate the number of volumes of a technical report?

Comment: Is your question if `@techreport` will take the field `volumes` in the current version of biblatex or in a future release? If you wonder about the current release you can just check the manual or try it.

Comment: It is not indicated in the manual as being supported.

Comment: Also, it does not appear to work, at least with the verbose-trad2 style I am presently using. Any other ideas on how to indicate number of volumes. Should I use the Note field?

Answer (score 5):

You could alter the bibliography style. For `verbose-trad2` it is defined primarily by `standard.bbx`. The code below will incorporate `volumes`, `volume`, `maintitle` and `part` fields for `@report` in a manner consistent with `@book`. Note that `@techreport` is just an alias for `@report` with `type = {techreport}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{% based on report and book drivers from standard.bbx
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isrn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Techreport{padhye,
  author      = {Padhye, Jitendra and Firoiu, Victor and Towsley, Don},
  maintitle       = {A Stochastic Model of TCP Reno Congestion Avoidance and Control},
  institution     = {University of Massachusetts},
  number      = {99-02},
  location  = {Amherst, Mass.},
  date        = {1999}}
@Techreport{padhye:mv,
  author      = {Padhye, Jitendra and Firoiu, Victor and Towsley, Don},
  maintitle       = {A Stochastic Model of TCP Reno Congestion Avoidance and Control},
  institution     = {University of Massachusetts},
  volumes       = {2},
  number      = {99-02},
  location  = {Amherst, Mass.},
  date        = {1999}}
@Book{knuth:ct,
  author      = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title       = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volumes     = {5},
  publisher   = {Addison-Wesley},
  location    = {Reading, Mass.},
  date        = {1984/1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Technical report: \cite{padhye} \\
\\
Multi-volume technical report: \cite{padhye:mv} \\
\\
Multi-volume book: \cite{knuth:ct}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, which has not only solved my immediate problem, but helped to teach me a little about how Biblatex styles work.